# Extending class, date based generic views in django and get_context_data?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to extend a simple date based view (using the 1.3 generic class approach) with my own mixin "BaseViewMixin":

```
class BaseViewMixin(object):
    """define some basic context for our views"""

    model = Alert
    month_format = "%m"
    date_field = "date"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """extra context"""
        context = super(BaseViewMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["CACHE_SERVERS"] = settings.CACHE_SERVERS
        return context


    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(BaseViewMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class IndexView(BaseViewMixin, TodayArchiveView):

    template_name= "index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        queryset = Alert.objects.default(self.day)
        tickets = Alert.objects.tickets(self.day)
        alert_groups = []
        for item in tickets:
            alert_groups.append({"ticket": item, "alerts": queryset.filter(ticket=item["ticket"])})
        context["alert_groups"] = alert_groups
        return context
```

The problem is that all of the date based things you normally get in the context are wiped out as soon as I override the get_context_data method for my IndexView class. Why is that? I would expect {{ day }}, {{ previous_day }} etc to show up in the context, as well as self. When I remove my get_context_data method all the generic date stuff works.

urls.py entry is just:

```
url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

Comment: `{{ day }}, {{ previous_day }}` where are they defined? `TodayArchiveView`?

Comment: TodayArchiveView should provide the same behavior as [DayArchiveView](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/class-based-views/#django.views.generic.dates.DayArchiveView). In my example class I'm using self.day which should work the same as context["day"], which is available in index.html. Problem is self.day and context["day"] are None. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Seems related to [this bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16074). Drives me crazy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it which allows me to reuse code. I'm still not understanding why `get_context_data` wipes out the `TodayArchiveView` context the way I define it in my original question. It seems that using the scenario below would do the same thing to my mixin but it doesn't. The ViewMixin context is preserved when calling `get_context_data` in `DateMixin`.

```
class ViewMixin(object):
    """define some basic context for our views"""

    model = Alert

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """extra context"""
        context = super(ViewMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["CACHE_SERVERS"] = settings.CACHE_SERVERS
        return context

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ViewMixin, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

class DateMixin(object):

    month_format = "%m"
    date_field = 'date'

    def get_alert_groups(self):
        none, qs, dated_items = self.get_dated_items()
        day = dated_items["day"]
        queryset = Alert.objects.default(day)
        tickets = Alert.objects.tickets(day)
        alert_groups = []
        for item in tickets:
            alert_groups.append({"ticket": item, "alerts": queryset.filter(ticket=item["ticket"])})
        return alert_groups

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DateMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["alert_groups"] = self.get_alert_groups()
        return context

class IndexView(ViewMixin, DateMixin, TodayArchiveView):

    template_name= "index.html"
```

Comment: today archive view gets wiped because in your original example you define your additional context within the view mixin but not within the datemixin. Just a blind shot guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arise because you're inhereting from 2 classes.

`context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)` will initialise the context with the method from `BaseViewMixin` not `TodayArchiveView` (super walks base classes from left to right) --> context variables from `TodayArchiveView` will be lost.

I think you can do this:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context_day = super(BaseViewMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context = dict(context, **context_day)
    ...
```

Comment: This got my hopes up but context_day still does not return the expected context. Even if I put:   `context_day = super(TodayArchiveView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)` I still don't access to TodayArchiveView's context when it is listed in the class `IndexView(BaseViewMixin, TodayArchiveView)`.

Comment: `TodayArchiveView` is your class right? is there an override of `get_context_data` in `TodayArchiveView`?

Comment: `TodayArchiveView` is a django generic view which inherits `BaseDateListView` which has `get_context_data` and it doesn't override it.

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer to your question, but considering the fact that your goal seems to be adding a certain context to more than one view a [context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) might be a good solution!

Comment: Yes, that occurred to me too but now I'm obsessed with making this work correctly.

Comment: I understand :). Did you try changing the order in which `IndexView` inherits from the other classes?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and order doesn't seem to make a difference. When `get_context_data` is defined on any class inheriting `TodayArchiveView` it disappears from the context. Even with single inheritance (no mixin) it gets lost.